# Get JS src params inside of JS file

Tags: javascript

I've got a `JS` file called `test.js`, I'd like to pull in and utilize params that are attached to the extension of this file, but for some reason when I console log the results, I'm not seeing them.

How can I use the URL of a JS file to bring in variables, e.g:

```html
<script src="test.js?var1=value1&var2=value2"></script>
```

The contents of my JS file is:

```js
const search = window.location.search
console.log(search) <-- not seeing var1 or var2
```

What am I missing?

P.S: I cannot define a variable outside of the JS file and then use it within, surely there's a way to use the attached vars on the URL?

Comment: Those values are not passed to the script. The script is executed by the page, and so the script will only have the page's search values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.location.search` returns the query string part of the *URL*[*the current location of the document*]. If you want to access the src of the script element, you may assign any unique identifier to the tag and may access the `src` property.

To access search parameters, you may use [`new URL(src)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL)

```js
let src = document.getElementById('src').src;
console.log('src - ', src);
const url = new URL(src);
console.log('search params - ', url.search);
```

```html
<script src="test.js?var1=value1&var2=value2" id="src"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

`window.location` is the location of the HTML document the script is running inside.

To get the value of the `src` attribute you need to use [`document.currentScript`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/currentScript) to get the element, then you can read its `src` property (and then you can parse it with [`URL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL)).

Unless you are sending the values to the server hosting the JS for server side processing, you'd likely be better off using [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) instead.

```html
<script data-foo="example">
    console.log(document.currentScript.dataset.foo);
</script>
```

Comment: I liked it :) :)